# Best way to handle legacy urls in django

Tags: django

I am working on a big news publishing platform. Basically rebuilding everything from ground zero with django. Now as we are almost ready for the launch I need to handle legacy url redirects. What is the best way to do it having in mind that I have to deal with tenths of thousands of legacy urls?

Logic should work like this: If none of existing urls/views where matched run that url thorough legacy Redirect urls patterns/views to see if it can provide some redirect to the new url before returning 404 error.

How do I do that?

Comment: Either you want to separate your "legacy" urls in its own urls.py or you want Nginx rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome, achieved that by using custom middleware:

```
from django.http import Http404
from legacy.urls import urlpatterns

class LegacyURLsMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code != 404:
            return response
        for resolver in urlpatterns:
            try:
                match = resolver.resolve(request.path[1:])
                if match:
                    return match.func(request, *match.args, **match.kwargs)
            except Http404:
                pass
        return response
```

Simply add this middleware as a last middleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list. Then use urls.py file in your legacy app to declare legacy urls and views which will handle permanent redirects. DO NOT include your legacy urls in to main urls structure. This middleware does it for you, but in a bit different way.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a fallback view that will try to handle any url not handled by your patterns. I see two options.

1. Just create a "default" pattern. It's important to this pattern to
   be    the last within your urlpatterns!

   in your urls.py:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns(
       '',
       # all your patterns
       url(r'^.+/', 'app.views.fallback')
   )
   ```

   in your views.py:

   ```
   from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

   def fallback(request):
       if is_legacy(request.path):
           return HttpResponseRedirect(convert(request.path))
       raise Http404
   ```
2. Create a custom http 404 handler.

   in your urls.py:

   ```
   handler404 = 'app.views.fallback'
   ```

   in your views.py

   ```
   from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
   from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

   def fallback(request):
       if is_legacy(request.path):
           return HttpResponseRedirect(convert(request.path))
       return page_not_found(request)
   ```

   it may seem to be a nicer solution but it will only work if you set DEBUG setting to False and provide custom 404 template.

Comment: @Simanas no, the new urls will be handled traditional way: you just declare a pattern for '/whitepapers/6-ways-to-make-your-life-better/' url with a proper handler. And the fallback view will try to handle old ones: check if requested view is a legacy one and redirect to its new equivalent.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, handler would work, but it looks like it's not designed for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jacobian's [django-multiurl](https://github.com/jacobian-archive/django-multiurl). There is a [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16774) to address the issue someday, but for now `django-multiurl` works very good.

Before:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('/app/(\w+)/$', app.views.people),
    url('/app/(\w+)/$', app.views.place),  # <-- Never matches
)
```

After:

```
# urls.py
from multiurl import multiurl, ContinueResolving
from django.http import Http404

urlpatterns = patterns('', multiurl(
    url('/app/(\w+)/$', app.views.people), # <-- Tried 1st
    url('/app/(\w+)/$', app.views.place),  # <-- Tried 2nd (only if 1st raised Http404)
    catch=(Http404, ContinueResolving)
))
```